# Sync folders over FTP

Tags: windows-7, ftp

First an explanation about syncing *folders* instead of *files*. The folders in question has images that are not going to be edited and updated with the FTP server, but simply new images added to them.

Is there a way to synchronize the presence of the images on both the client on server? The client server is a Windows machine, and while some may suggest using rsync and whatnot, the server is Linux-based but it's a shared webhost so no direct access other than FTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some FTP clients would do that - [cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) is what i'd use (since i use it anyway) with the [mirror folders option](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/sync#OnlyDownloadFiles). Since you will be adding and not modifying, and this uses the timestamp only, it should work out what to move fairly quickly.

Comment: Any equivalent for Linux-based OSes? The images live on a computer not mine, and I would like to know what I can use on my Linux-based system.

Comment: Can a sync shortcut be created, so I run cyberduck and let it sync folders?

Comment: Well, neither of that was in the original question. I'll need to poke at it. Filezilla might be a truely cross platform option and seems to support synchronisation. No idea about passing rules to anything via command line, it will need more poking

Comment: It's okay, those are the bonus questions if you will. :P I did not find anything similar in Filezilla other than synchronized browsing, which is not what I'm looking for.